# $\mathrm d$ as an operator - math implications of the upright ("mathrm" or Roman) d.

Tags: calculus, notation

I have heard or read that the reason why in calculus dx is seen so often typed as $\mathrm d x$ is because $\mathrm d$ is an [*operator*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/168378/527495) or a *symbol*, while $x$ is in cursive because it is a *variable*. This seems to be the understanding also in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1715787/527495).

But I'd like to ask for a bit more background about what type of *operator* $\mathbb d$ is (is it a function, for example?)- I know that in Riemman integrals it serves the purpose of partitioning the $x$ domain into infinitesimally thin slices, but there has to be more to it...

As for the *symbol* explanation, aren't we always dealing with [symbols](http://qr.ae/TU1s3B)? Isn't $x$ just as much of a symbol as $\mathrm d$?

Incidentally, I see that there is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1289074/527495) that reads identical to this one, but it refers to a specific situation.

---

Thanks for the comments - still not clear on how to splice them all... So let me rephrase the question: Is it like this

$$\left.
\begin{array}{l}
\text{if $d$ is the exterior derivative operator:}&\mathrm dx\\
\text{if $d$ is part of the symbol of an element of }V^*\text{:}&dx
\end{array}
\right\}
$$

?

---

Here's some [informative interaction on the sister community tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator):

[image]

Comment: It's just a convention. Don't read too much into it.

Comment: For me, $\mathrm{d}$ is simply a convention that is designed to avoid confusion when one really wants to save $d$ for other meanings. Similarly I see a trend of using $\mathrm{e}$ for the natural constant, $\mathrm{i}$ for the imaginary unit, etc.

Comment: Actually $dx$ is a single symbol that represents an element in the dual space.

Comment: @egreg Are you implying that seasoned mathematicians go through the extra $\LaTeX$ pain with the sole purpose to differentiate $\mathrm dx$ from the basis of $V^*,$ i.e. $dx^i$?

Comment: @justquestions I'm a seasoned mathematician as well as a seasoned $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ user and never use other than an italic “d” for this purpose.

Comment: @egreg Totally... I read your profile, and was trying to get more elaboration from you - perhaps a formal answer?

Comment: $d$ is of course an operator, which is the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative)

Comment: @egreg: Fortunately, the cotangent vector field $dx$ happens to be the result of applying the exterior derivative $d$ to the scalar field $x$, so we can interpret it either way.

Comment: @egreg Could you clarify what you meant by "this purpose" on your prior comment - do you use italics for both purposes (element in the dual space and differential), of just for the dual space?

Comment: Hopefully no-one would write $d$ and $\mathrm{d}$ to mean different things - I wouldn't like to spend all my time peering at slightly different fonts, trying to distinguish them. I think the choice between them is just a matter of taste.

Comment: @justquestions For the purpose of integrals

Comment: For me it an operator that only makes sense in the context of $${\rm d}\square = \sum_i \frac{\partial \square}{\partial x_i} {\rm d}x_i$$ the common notation $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}$ is somewhat of a misnomer.